# Reversing Electronic Transfer of Money

Tags: united-states, money-transfer

Suppose a friend sends me $500 through Chase Quickpay, and I accept it. The money goes into my account, and is available for further sending/withdrawal. Is it possible for Chase to reverse the transfer of money so that the money goes back to the sender (if the sender requests), even after I have the transferred money already in my account? What if I withdraw/use up the money before they reverse the transaction?

Answer (score 5):

From [Chase FAQ](https://www.chase.com/index.jsp?pg_name=ccpmapp/individuals/shared/page/quickpay_faqs#6) it looks like this is a regular ACH transfer. ACH transactions can be reversed under certain conditions. I haven't been able to find some authoritative link on this, so I suggest [this (thenest.com budgeting blog)](http://budgeting.thenest.com/rules-ach-reversal-24728.html) instead:

> **Allowed Reasons**
>
> You can have ACH transactions reversed for one of three reasons under
>   the rules: wrong money amount, wrong account or duplicated
>   transactions. For example, if your mortgage bill is for $756.00, but
>   your lender's website messes up and you're charged $856.00, the
>   transaction is reversible it because it's the wrong dollar amount. If
>   the website charges you $756.00 twice, the second duplicated
>   transaction is reversible.
>
> **Reversal Procedures**
>
> You might have to bring a mistake to the originator's attention to get
>   it fixed. Only the originator -- the person or company taking or
>   sending money -- can ask for a reversal. For example, if you have a
>   transaction for a wrong dollar amount from your lender's website, the
>   originator is the lender. An originator is supposed to send the
>   reversal within 24 hours of the error's discovery and within five
>   banking days of the original transaction. When a reversal is required
>   because of a wrong amount or wrong account, the originator must send a
>   correcting entry with the right information.
>
> **Bank's Responsibility**
>
> A bank should honor an ACH reversal, even if it means debiting a
>   customer's account again because of a correcting transaction. However,
>   the bank doesn't have to debit your account if you closed it or the
>   new transaction would overdraw it. Your bank does have to tell you if
>   a correcting entry is going to take money out of your account, but the
>   bank doesn't need your permission to do it.